# Unable to negotiate with 52.119.168.71 port 22 when setup SSH AWS connections on Window 11

Tags: git, ssh, aws-codecommit

I am following this link to setup ssh codecommit AWS

[Aws setup doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html)

At the step 10

```
PS C:\Users\mrdar\.ssh> ssh git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.119.161.60)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0pJx9SQpkbPUAHwy58UVIq0IHcyo1fwCpOOuVgcAWPo.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
```

and the result:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com,52.119.161.60' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.Connection to git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com closed.
```

There are four files in .ssh folder:

```
codecommit_rsa
codecommit_rsa.pub
config
known_hosts(this generated after I ran this command `ssh git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`)
```

and then I perform this command on git bash:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com...
```

and I got this issue:

```
Unable to negotiate with 52.94.210.119 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can't clone my git repo from AWS codecommit, what will I do next ?, I have tried some solutions on google but none of them work.
I do the same with the new lap and it worked, I don't know why my old laptop did not work:@.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but managed to solve it by setting up a `config` file, verifying the `ssh` connection, then `git` for cloning and committing. I have multiple SSH keys for different SCM platforms (**CodeCommit** and **GitHub**), so when `git` cached my GitHub ssh key, it would not switch back to my AWS one for CodeCommit. The result was the same error.

I solved the problem by these three steps:

1. Create a fully articulated `config` file at the `~/.ssh/` path

   - Specify `ssh-rsa` algorithm tolerance
   - Provide your **SSH Key ID** as `User` (looks like `APKA████████████████`)
2. Cache the key password using `ssh IDENT@git-code-commit.REGION.amazonaws.com` format

   - `IDENT` is your **SSH Key ID**
   - `REGION` is the default AWS region
3. Cloning locally using available CodeCommit schemes

   - `HTTPS` when using either Git credentials with IAM user or credential helper included with AWS CLI
   - `HTTPS (GRC)` when using `git-remote-codecommit` command
   - `SSH` when using SSH public/private key pair with IAM user

Details on the differences at [*Step 2: Create a local repo*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-set-up-folders) of [**AWS** ▸ **Documentation** ▸ **CodeCommit** ▸ **User Guide**.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)

#### Cache your ssh key and test ssh

This is not a prerequisite, but it establishes that things are working and locally caches your SSH password for a few minutes.

```
me@ps ~$ ssh APKA████████████████@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com closed.
```

Strangely, AWS docs do not specify using the **SSH Key ID** to test, but I found it necessary to get a connection. The **SSH Key ID** can be found in the IAM console in the profile for your IAM user:

[image: Find your SSH CodeCommit Key Id]

As shown in this screenshot, the key ID starts with `APKA…`. Once you `SSH` in successfully, CLI navigate to your locally cloned repo and make sure the remotes are correct.

```
me@ps ~$git remote --verbose
origin  https://git-codecommit.████████████.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/████████████ (fetch)
origin  https://git-codecommit.████████████.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/████████████ (push)
```

#### SSH Config File

Make sure your `config` or `config.txt` in your `~/.ssh/` path is [correctly set up](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config). The `Host` name pattern should match your AWS git remotes. Depending on your ssh version, you may need to explicitly enable `dsa`. Here's what mine looks like:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dsa
    User APKA████████████████
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
Host *
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub
```

This is just one possible solution. I found many of these steps by following the troubleshooting instructions here: [AWS ▸ Documentation ▸ CodeCommit ▸ User Guide ▸ Troubleshooting ▸ Troubleshooting SSH connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssh.html)

Comment: I do the command `ssh IDENT@git-commit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` and add a line to config(not config.txt) file  a line `HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` , then I run `git clone ssh://IDENT@my repo link`. Then it shows up the error like this `IDENT@git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I did clean install window 11, then do the first ssh on this lap then this error happens. It used to work normally before.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had my cygwin git access to AWS Codecommit break.

I needed `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` in my config file in addition to `HashKeyAlgorithms` mentioned by Mavaddat Javid.